# Why "clearInterval" doesn't work inside conditional "mouseover" event listener?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, callback, setinterval, mouseover

I'm working on a Chrome extension. After a storage.sync.get (to load user prefs), we execute a function which sets a listener on "DOMContentLoaded" to attach "mouseover" listeners on a set of nodes. Each "mouseover" listener first starts a setInterval which calls a function. This function checks for some elements to load, when loaded elements -> ***it should clearInterval***. 
BUT IT DOESN'T, INTERVALS CONTINUE RUNNING. WHY?

```
chrome.storage.sync.get('prefs', (r)=>{callback(r)});

function do_smth(i) {
    null !== document.querySelector('div.some-class') && (clearInterval(s[i]), [statement], [statement])
}

var s = [], callback = function(e) {
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", ()=>{
        document.querySelector("#mydiv").childNodes.forEach((r,i)=>{
            r.addEventListener('mouseover', ()=>{s[i] = setInterval(()=>{do_smth(i)}, 10)
            })
        })
    })
}
```

Comment: A better strategy seems to be using MutationObserver because 1) mouseover bubbles, meaning nested elements will trigger it too and thus start several intervals but save just the last one `i`, 2) the page may accidentally clear your content script's interval ids since these are shared. P.S. the first comment seems to be right as you only clear the intervals *conditionally* but you start them *unconditionally* so there will be inevitably times when the two don't match.

Comment: @woxxom MutationObserver is not fast enough to catch async loading content before it’s displayed on screen, I used that in the beginning. Still not sure what happens with the intervals, because extensions have their own protected JS VM so all scopes are private, not shared with page unless you explicitly inject scripts in page DOM. But as I said earlier, even if there are multiple internal calls to setInterval, there’s a symmetrical number of correct ID calls to clearInterval too...

Comment: 1) "MutationObserver is not fast enough to catch async loading content before it’s displayed on screen," - It's the other way around. In JavaScript event loop MutationObserver runs as a microtask, whereas intervals run as a separate task that can execute after layout is presented on screen. Evidently you've used MO incorrectly. 2) intervals are shared via DOM, it's not a part of the isolated content script world, 3) since the reported problem is that intervals keep running, it can only mean your code doesn't clear them symmetrically.

Comment: @wOxxOm not here to argue with you, but last time I used MutationObsever in this particular case (inside pages with infinity scroll that use popstate, prefetch and async content loading), it worked poorly compared to the good'ol setInterval.

Comment: I can guarantee you MutationObserver is always faster just because it's implemented that way internally, which is why it's used for observables in Polymer and other well-known libraries. Of course it should be used properly. My point has been - since my first comment here - that MO is a better solution for the problem of detecting DOM changes and reacting immediately.